# increment and decrement between 2 buttons

Tags: jquery

I have 2 buttons and these 2 buttons will increase the total number of clicks. (The total is count separately)
An user only allow to select 1 of them which means if user has previously clicked on buttonA and click buttonB again. ButtonA will - 1 and ButtonB will + 1.

I have following codes and there is a problem. If no clicked before the buttons would be

```
buttonA (0) - buttonB (0).
```

If an user click buttonA suppose to be `buttonA (1) - buttonB (0)` 
but the following codes show

```
buttonA (1) - buttonB (-1)
```

What I want is, the button ONLY decrease the button which user clicked it before.
And how can I improve my code? It seems messy.

```
$this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
if ($this.is('span[name="ans_yes"]')) {
    yes_no = 1;
    currentVal = parseInt($this.find('.badge').html());
    $this.find('.badge').html(currentVal + 1);

    currentVal2 = parseInt($id.find('.ans-no').html());
    $id.find('.ans-no').html(currentVal2 - 1);
} else {
    yes_no = 0;
    currentVal = parseInt($this.find('.badge').html());
    $this.find('.badge').html(currentVal + 1);

    currentVal2 = parseInt($id.find('.ans-yes').html());
    console.log(currentVal2);
    $id.find('.ans-yes').html(currentVal2 - 1);
}
```

Updated - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vzhen/TtkDG/)

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net with corresponding html

Comment: @charlietfl i added the demo

Comment: Are there going to be multiple buttonA's and buttonB's on the page, or only one of each? Are the values only 0 or 1? We could use some more details to figure out what you're actually going for.

Comment: They are multiple buttonA's and B on the same page and I already figured out this part by using the unique id. No, the values are increment by users clicks (vote).

Comment: @DavidKiger so if user previously voted buttonA, and if the same user change to buttonB then buttonA will - 1 and buttonB + 1. But if the user has no vote before. No button will - 1. Make sense?

Comment: is idea that wil only be one or zero? Or if keep clicking `yes` will keep adding? If first case the code is far too overcomplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to keep your HTML structure pretty similar, but I completely hosed the JS. You'll need to refit your `active` classes if necessary, because without any CSS I wasn't sure what they were being used for (if anything)

```
var answered = {};  

$('.ans-yes-no').on('click', function(e) {
    var questionId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var currentAnswer = answered[questionId];
    var count = parseInt($(this).children('.badge').html());

    if ( currentAnswer == $(this).attr('name') ) {
        // Turning off
        $(this).children('.badge').html(count-1);
        delete answered[questionId];
    } else {
        // If we have a different answer, turn that off
        if ( currentAnswer ) {
            var oldCountEl = $("#"+questionId).children("span[name="+currentAnswer+"]").children('.badge');
            var oldCount = parseInt(oldCountEl.html());
            oldCountEl.html( oldCount - 1 );
        }

        // Turning on
        $(this).children('.badge').html(count+1);
        answered[questionId] = $(this).attr('name');
    }
});
```

Demo working at http://jsfiddle.net/TtkDG/3/, with multiple instances of buttonA and buttonB.

EDIT: To be clear, I did have to wrap the buttons in a containing div with a question identifier. Just make sure you don't miss that.

Comment: I think this is what i want.

Comment: back again because cannot figure out what 
`var answered = {};`
`answered[topic_id];` mean

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on arrays in Javascript. Take a look at http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/. It's long, but should hopefully help.

Comment: {} and array()  are equal ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a variable `didtheuserclick` which is false in the beginning and check if the variable is true than subtract, else ignore the subtract part, and set the variable to true at the end of the click function, I made a demo, http://jsfiddle.net/TtkDG/1/

Also you could use a simple integer variable with increment on each click and check if the variable is equal to 1, it's the same logic but if using it just for this is pointless to increment a variable, especially if you are going to reach high numbers.

hope it helps!

Comment: There is a problem in your demo. Click buttonA again and again will cause buttonB -1 because as you said, theuserdidclick before.

Answer (score 0):

I created a single function that will toggle the value of the `badge`. If increment is less than zero it prints zero.

Also note is simpler to add another class to the elements than use `name`

```
 $('.ans-yes-no').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var $this = $(this),
          $otherBtn = $this.siblings('.ans-yes-no');

      var $btnWrap = $this.closest('.topic-footer');
      /* check if user has already selected, test "active" class length*/
      var alreadyVoted = $btnWrap.find('.active').length;
      if (alreadyVoted) {
          if ($this.is('.active')) {
              /* do nothing if already active?? */
              return;
          } else {
              $this.add($otherBtn).toggleClass('active');
          }
      } else {
          $this.addClass('active');
      }

      toggleValue($this, 'up');
      toggleValue($otherBtn, 'down');
  });

  function toggleValue($element, direction) {
      $element.find('.badge').text(function (i, currVal) {
          var value = parseInt(currVal, 10);
          direction == 'up' ? value++ : value--;
          return value > -1 ? value : 0;
      })
  }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MZyxW/

It's not 100% clear what behavior you want as far as user being able to keep adding or if you will update the html each page load with `active` class if user has already clciked an answer